# Handling different versioned packages within same file

Tags: go, import

We have two different version packages to our database. Some of our projects still use the old db, while the new ones use the new db

We have a package `conn`

```
import(
    "gopkg.in/db/pkg.v3"
)

...
func connect() {
   y := dbpkg.New()
   ...
}
```

Now we have `gopkg.in/db/pkg.v4` coming in. Both `pkg.v3` and `pkg.v4` expose very similar functions except, of course, the changes between the db versions. Our `conn` package however is using the standard parts which are commonly available between both `v3` and `v4`. Therefore, we would like to maintain the package `conn` as it is and in compile time determine whether we have to include `pkg.v3` or `pkg.v4`. Is that possible?

If not, then another thought process is to create a new local package `pkg` (which `conn` shall use) and have two files `pkg_v3.go` and `pkg_v4.go` in `pkg` which can be compiled based on build tags. In that as well, how to automatically expose some/all the functions from the `pkg.v3 or pkg.v4` through `pkg`.

We would like to avoid duplicating the whole `conn` package just to change this one line `pkg.v3` or `pkg.v4`

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use build tags for this, would you need to call different versions in the same function?

You could still load multiple packages and use different aliases (something that would be possible with [this package](https://github.com/olivere/elastic#elastic-60) for example).

```
import(
    pkgVersionA "gopkg.in/db/pkg.v1"
    pkgVersionB "gopkg.in/db/pkg.v2"
)

...
func connect() {
   y := pkgVersionA.New()
   x := pkgVersionB.New()
   ...
}
```

Comment: `conn` uses the standard functions that both packages expose and hence just changing the import would work correctly. Otherwise, we have to duplicate all the code in it (which is what we would like to avoid). So our real goal is to determine at compile time whether it is `v3` or `v4`.